# PHP - List pulled from one field exploding commas

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The title may be a bit misleading, to be honest I don't know what this feature is called.

I have a field which will contain a list of a users skills in the database, the skills will be separated by commas.

When I then echo the field, I want each skill after the commas to be in a new list element.

So it'll echo like this in the HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>Cycling</li>
<li>Driving</li>
<li>Running</li>
</ul>
```

However in the field 'skills' it'll look like:

> Cycling, Driving, Running

I read that you need to explode the comma however I have no idea how to accomplish it.

Comment: Simply see [PHP docs on explode()](http://www.php.net/explode) for example, it's as easy as `$array = explode(",", $skills);`. You might want to `trim()` the skills afterwards.

Comment: ... and the see [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and try `$str = implode("</li>\n<li>", $array)` and you are half way there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [explode](http://www.php.net/explode):

```
$activities = explode(',', $activities);
```

Filter to trim the values of the array (so there's no whitespace on them) using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$activities = array_map('trim', $activities);
```

Then glue it back up with [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$activities = '<li>' . implode('</li><li>' . $activities) . '</li>';
```

Put it all together, with a bit of defensive programming:

```
$activities = explode(',', $activities);
if ( $activities ) {
    $activities = array_map('trim', $activities);
    $activities = '<li>' . implode('</li><li>' . $activities) . '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with  `explode` ([php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)).

```
$activities = 'Cycling, Driving, Running';
$exploded = explode(', ', $activities);
foreach ($exploded as $activity) {
    echo '<li>' . $activity . '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [*str_replace*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$skills = "Cycling, Driving, Running";
echo '<ul><li>' . str_replace(", ", "</li><li>", $skills) . '</li></ul>';
```

Comment: What if you need to add classes and stuff, later? :P

Comment: Then you add them later. Don't see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = "Cycling, Driving, Running";
$elements = explode(", ",$list);

echo "<ul>";
foreach($elements as $element){
    echo "<li>$element</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to this code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working now! :)

Thanks to who contributed.

Code I used:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <?php
    $activities_q = "SELECT skills FROM users WHERE uid='".$row['uid']."'";
    $activities = $row['skills'];
    $exploded = explode(',', $activities);
    foreach ($exploded as $activity) {
        echo '<li class="list-group-item">' . $activity . '</li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
```